# Vuetify3 v-combobox and cypress: How to identify list items?

Tags: cypress, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am in the process of migrating to vuetify3, and I'm using cypress (the cypress studio) for testing.

The `<v-combobox>` gives me a dropdown with items, but these are not easily referencable with css selectors. Cypress studio generates stuff like

```js
cy.get('.v-overlay__content > .v-list > :nth-child(2) > .v-list-item__content > .v-list-item-title').click();
```

... which isn't readable for a human and will break if the dropdown list gets modified (for example, prepend a list item).

The best solution I came up with yet would be to give each list item a `data-cy` attribute; but how to do that properly? It seems to me that vuetify3 docs are still sparse on how to use the `item` slot (cf. https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/); its workings seem to differ from vuetify2. By using the `item` slot like,

```html
<v-combobox>
  <template #item="scope">
    myListItem
  </template>
</v-combobox>
```

... the list items are not clickable any more.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify3-v-combobox-and-cypress-how-to-identify-list-items-gzfs71?file=/src/App.vue

**EDIT** Of course I could write the Cypress test code myself. But my premise is to use Cypress Studio, which CAN generate meaningful CSS selectors if possible, i. e. if there are `id` or `data-cy` attributes in the HTML code. But vuetify does not generate such. So I ask, how can I attach `data-cy` attributes to list items?

Answer (score 0):

I think your selector is a bit more complex than needed

you can simplify to just the relevant elements

```js
// get based on value
cy.get(".v-overlay-container .v-list-item").contains("Programming").click();

// get based on order (force: true is required if the combo box is still animating)
cy.get(".v-overlay-container .v-list-item").eq(2).click({ force: true });
```

example used

```html
<template>
  Click this combobox:
  <v-combobox :items="items" id="combo" />
</template>

<script>
import { VCombobox } from "vuetify/components";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      items: ["Programming", "Design", "Vue", "Vuetify"],
    };
  },
  components: { VCombobox },
};
</script>
```

test

```js
describe("", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("http://10.0.0.248:8080/");
  });

  it("select with content", () => {
    cy.get("#combo").click();
    cy.get(".v-overlay-container .v-list-item").contains("Programming").click();
    cy.get("#combo").should("have.value", "Programming");
  });

  it("select with order", () => {
    cy.get("#combo").click();
    cy.get(".v-overlay-container .v-list-item").eq(2).click({ force: true });
    cy.get("#combo").should("have.value", "Vue");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However my premise is not to create the cypress test code on my own, but to use Cypress Studio. I have clarified my question, see above.